# Worldbuilding is getting out of hand.

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

I'm on a long and complicated journey with a world I'm building. Does anyone know of a worldbuilding tool for keeping track of it all? My usual methods don't really work right now. I mean a tool in the same way that Scrivener is a tool for writing fiction or Word is a tool for writing. I use mind mapping and calc for making notes, connecting ideas etc already.

Comment: What's the difference between "a tool for writing fiction" and what you're doing?